# Why does the WinDBG command "!error" not work as expected?

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, driver, windbg

It is very common for me to query the meaning of an `NTSTATUS` value.

However, I always get nothing by the WinDBG command !error like the following:

> kd> !error 0xC0000008 1
>
> Error code: (NTSTATUS) 0xC0000008 - Unable to get error code text

Why does the WinDBG command `!error` not work as expected?

Thanks in advance.

PS. 0xC0000008 indicates STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE

Comment: What version of WinDbg are you using? This works for me using 6.2.9200.16384 AMD64 version

Comment: What does this have to do with kernel?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you should set locale
for example:
0: kd> .locale ".1251"

http://perfect-coding.blogspot.ru/2011/06/windbg-error-extension-and-locale.html

Comment: The method has no effects on my machine.